# In this context, what does the following npm documentation mean by "running npm packages globally"?

Tags: node.js, npm, documentation

If my understanding is correct, then `npm install` adds the package on a per-project basis by default. On the other hand, if I do `npm install -g` the package is added to the global scope. However, can somebody please explain what [the npm documentation is talking about here](https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-packages-globally)?

> Tip: If you are using npm 5.2 or higher, we recommend using npx to **run
> packages globally.**

To run a package globally? As in, to be able to run packages installed by `npm install -g`?

PS - In order to try certain packages without installing them first, I do understand that one is able to run them via `npx`.

Comment: I *believe* the recommendation is to use `npx` *instead of* installing a package globally. I'm not completely confident to make this into an answer, though - hopefully somebody confirms it or has a correct explanation.

Comment: Aaah! Okay @VLAZ. That makes sense... Thank you so much!!

Comment: Also, I find the question quite appropriate. I don't think the documentation is clear enough and, honestly, the whole `npx` thing is not explained well enough. It's a good tool but the reasoning and motivation for how and when to use it is lacking in many regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`npx`](https://github.com/npm/npx) is recommended for running global npm packages

> By default, npx will check whether `<command>` exists in `$PATH`, or in the local project binaries, and execute that. If `<command>` is not found, it will be installed prior to execution.

so rather then installing the package globally using npm and running it, you can leverage npx (which has much more features)